# I'm looking to install turf against concrete patio slab, but the weep screed is in the way

Tags: concrete, slab, stucco, turf

I have a conundrum. The concrete slab depth ends right around the stucco weep screed on one side of the patio. I want to install turf and obviously won't be able to make it flush. There may be less than one inch of space between the end of the slab and the weep screed.

If I install the turf right where the slab ends, the blade height will be up in the weep screed. What are some options I have?

My current game plan is filling the void and then installing turf below the weep screed and lastly installing a transition piece to cover the ugly side view of the slab/foam and also as a way to prevent trip hazards with the step. Any ideas on if such a transition piece?

[image]

Comment: Is your concern being able to mow the grass that'd be below the stucco?  Perhaps you could add/update your pic to show exactly where you plan to turf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area needs some care before putting down any sod or landscaping.

The stucco over the sheathing should be fully sealed and painted. There is no need to allow any opening at the bottom for anything to weep.  If water gets behind the stucco it will cause a problem. The weep screed then is of no consequence.  Seal the bottom edge with caulk and paint.

As shown in this pic  [image]

Areas marked by blue need to be filled with a polyester caulk such as[Vulkem][2]

Then extra cement, as shown by the black lines, should be knocked off carefully.  Drilling some holes and hitting with a concrete chisel should do it.

Then scrape back the dirt from the foundation at least 6 inches deep, so it can be painted below grade. A good 2 or 3 coats to seal the home.

With painting done, back fill grading the soil away from the house and slab. as shown in yellow.

When the house wall is painted and sealed you can place your sod.  The plan should still be to have the base of the sod below the bottom of the wall.

Comment: Thanks for the notes for sealing the stucco. I understand painting below grade for the stucco wall but I'm still not sure how to deal with the thinner patio slab. Do I just backfill and grade from where the void begins? Would the top black line you drew on the extra cement be okay to put landscaping? I'm planning on artificial turf.

Comment: @Alan,  You would be ok planting your landscaping at or below the top black line.